# Making a cleveref String Lowercase

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, amsthm

I'm using `cleveref` to cross-reference my theorems throughout my document. However, since certain theorems are so popular, I much prefer to refer to them by names as opposed to their theorem numbers; but I would still like them to be clickable, so that clicking on a theorem's name, wherever it's mentioned, will take you straight to it.

To create custom string, I implemented the solution provided by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109864/78913), which can be shown in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, parskip, hyperref, cleveref}

% Theorems
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

% Solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109864/78913
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\cref{#1}\mynameref{#1}{\csname r@#1\endcsname}}
\newcommand{\Myref}[1]{\Cref{#1}\mynameref{#1}{\csname r@#1\endcsname}}

\def\mynameref#1#2{%
    \begingroup
    \edef\@mytxt{#2}%
    \edef\@mytst{\expandafter\@thirdoffive\@mytxt}%
    \ifx\@mytst\empty\else
    \space(\nameref{#1})\fi
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Group Actions}

    \begin{theorem}[Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem]
        \label{thm:ost}
        Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a finite set $X$. Then 
        \[|G| = \mathop{\mathrm{Orb}}(x) \times \mathop{\mathrm{Stab}}(x).\]
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{example}
        Let $G$ act on $X$, where $|G| = 55$ and $|X| = 18$. Show that the action has at least two fixed points.

        By the \nameref{thm:ost}, ...
    \end{example}

\end{document}
```

This code provides the following output:

[image: Figure 1]

Is there a way I can change the label so that the text is in lower-case? I tried using `\MakeLowercase{}`, but this didn't work. And is there a way I can modify the label in general? If I have something like "Cauchy's Theorem" for example, I'd like to have it appear as "Cauchy's **t**heorem" in text, with a lower-case `t`.

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: cref macros are not expandable, in most cases

Comment: Actually, you're asking about a lowercase nameref.

Comment: You should have `\DeclareMathOperator{\Orb}{Orb}` and `\DeclareMathOperator{\Stab}{Stab}`, with `\lvert G\rvert=\lvert\Orb(x)\rvert\times\lvert\Stab(x)\rvert` rather than the awkward `\mathop` construction (requires `amsmath`, of course).

Comment: @egreg That's what I do in the actual document, I only switch to `\mathop` for the MWE. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to tell LaTeX explicitly how you want the theorem name capitalised. There's no way to automatically detect which words are proper nouns like "Cauchy" that should stay capitalised.

Referring to things by name falls more within the remit of the `nameref` package. `Cleveref` is concerned with referring to things by their label. But since you'll have to specify the correctly-capitalised theorem name explicitly anyway, there is a way to do it with just `cleveref` without much extra effort:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, parskip, hyperref, cleveref}

% Theorems
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\begin{document}
    \section{Group Actions}

    \begin{theorem}[Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem]
      \label{thm:ostnum}
      \label[ost]{thm:ostname}
      \crefformat{ost}{#2orbit-stabiliser theorem#3}
      \Crefformat{ost}{#2Orbit-stabiliser theorem#3}
      Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a finite set $X$. Then
      \[|G| = \mathop{\mathrm{Orb}}(x) \times \mathop{\mathrm{Stab}}(x).\]
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{example}
        Let $G$ act on $X$, where $|G| = 55$ and $|X| = 18$. Show that the action has at least two fixed points.

        By the \cref{thm:ostname}, which is given in \cref{thm:ostnum}, \dots
    \end{example}

\end{document}
```

This works by defining a new cross-reference type `ost`, and telling `cleveref` to format references to it using the correctly capitalised theorem name. The additional `thm:ostnum` label is just to demonstrate how you can still refer to the theorem by its label too, if desired.

If you want to do this often, it could be tidied up a bit by bundling the \label, \crefformat, \Crefformat and maybe even the theorem definition into a new macro or environment.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks @Toby Cubitt

Comment: A minor thing to point out: assuming you wanted to render the output "By the orbit-stabiliser theorem, which is given in theorem 1.1", I think you need to put `\label{thm:ostnum}` *before* the `\crefformat{}{}` lines.

Comment: @Luke Collins Indeed - edited my answer to fix this. Thanks! It's really that the unadorned \label{...} must come before the the \label[ost]{...}. The \crefformat's can go anywhere before the first reference to thm:ostname. Putting them in the preamble would be safest, but more confusing.

Comment: This is by no means a perfect solution. E.g. the need for the \crefformat's to come before the first reference, and the ordering requirements for the \label's. A better solution would be for the nameref package to allow multiple variants of theorem (or section) names to be specified for different purposes - one for the title, one for references in-text. (Cf. \crefname/format and \Crefname/format.) But as far as I know that would require enhancing the nameref package.

Answer (score 3):

I've written the `crossreftools` package some weeks ago (it's available on CTAN, TeXLive and MikTeX, current version is 0.4), which provides expandable extraction of the cross-reference information stored by `hyperref` and `cleveref`.

`\MakeLowercase` won't work with `\nameref`, since `\nameref` isn't expandable, so the name information has to be extracted first, then apply `\MakeLowercase`.

The name reference is done with `\crtrefname`, but this would not provide a hyperlink, which would make the whole issue unexpandable again. The hyper anchor can be extracted with `\crtrefanchor`, together with a `\hyperlink` wrapped in a new command, say `\lowernameref` this will give the lower case title.

Please note, that `\lowernameref` is unexpandable of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, parskip, hyperref, cleveref}

\usepackage{crossreftools}

% Theorems
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

% Solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109864/78913
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\cref{#1}\mynameref{#1}{\csname r@#1\endcsname}}
\newcommand{\Myref}[1]{\Cref{#1}\mynameref{#1}{\csname r@#1\endcsname}}

\newcommand{\lowernameref}[1]{\hyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#1}}{\MakeLowercase{\crtrefname{#1}}}}


\def\mynameref#1#2{%
    \begingroup
    \edef\@mytxt{#2}%
    \edef\@mytst{\expandafter\@thirdoffive\@mytxt}%
    \ifx\@mytst\empty\else
    \space(\nameref{#1})\fi
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Group Actions}

    \begin{theorem}[Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem]
        \label{thm:ost}
        Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a finite set $X$. Then 
        \[|G| = \mathop{\mathrm{Orb}}(x) \times \mathop{\mathrm{Stab}}(x).\]
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{example}
        Let $G$ act on $X$, where $|G| = 55$ and $|X| = 18$. Show that the action has at least two fixed points.

        By the \lowernameref{thm:ost}, ...
    \end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how something like 'by **C**auchy's **t**heorem' can be achieved though?

Comment: @LukeCollins: Sorry, not yet. TeX/LaTeX is bad in detecting lower/upper case

Comment: Load `textcase`, use `\MakeTextLowercase` instead of `\MakeLowercase` and input `\begin{theorem}[\NoCaseChange{Cauchy}]`